# n intersecting lines, every line of them is intersecting the other in 20 points, find all values of n.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I tried to solve this problem and the only value that i've found is 21; because you'll have then 21 lines are intersecting in the same point so the one line is intersecting the others in 20 points.

Comment: i think the problem meant 20 distinct points

Comment: I had something similar some time ago. The aim was to find the configuration with $9$ lines intersecting the others in a total of $18$ points. The solution is $3$ beams of $3$ lines with $5$ intersections points per line. Have a look at the picture : http://hpics.li/98d673d . As per your problem, two lines only $1$ point in common, so I guess it is similar to my problem, these are $20$ points overall, isn't it ?

Comment: @Lelouch : No, i'm sure of the problem context.